# How do I get rid of the comma in this array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, split

```js
const el_Demo = document.getElementById("demo") // demo element

function myFunction() {
  const stringSample = "how was your day?";

  const arrayObject = stringSample.split(" ", 2);
  el_Demo.textContent = arrayObject;

  const textValue = el_Demo.textContent;
  el_Demo.textContent = textValue.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"> ... result after click ...</p>

<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

If I split the comma , then the code results in the full words I've written in the str variable , and not only 2.
How do I get rid of the comma that appears?

Comment: The comma doesn't actually exist. Since an array is an object, javascript is converting the array to a string when adding it to the DOM.

Comment: Your array is fine, it contains the words "How" and "was". The comma is just there because you're trying to display the entire array itself.

Comment: Unclear what you expect to happen.... you have an array and you ouput it....

Comment: I would guess something like `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.join(" ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `join` it back with `res.join(" ");` you will convert it from an array to a string with no comma:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join(' ')` to join the array.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "how was your day?";
  var res = str.split(" ", 2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.join(' ');
  var txt = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = txt.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

Which produces

```
HOW WAS
```